# Spring Boot 2 WebSockets connection lost unexpectedly

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a Spring boot 1.5 + Angular5 application utilizing Websockets via SockJS, and was recently forced to upgrade to Spring boot 2.2.

Following the upgrade, my websocket is being closed after either a random period of time, or when a write to the websocket happens. When using Spring Boot 1.5, everything works perfectly.

Below is the configuration in Spring, using spring-boot-starter-websocket version: '2.2.4.RELEASE'

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/socket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
            .enableSimpleBroker("/nightly");
    }
}
```

I've also added the following security rules:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .antMatcher("/api/socket/**")
        .cors().and()
        .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

Client code:

```
initWebSocket() {
    const ws = new SockJS('/api/socket');
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    const that = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, () => {
        that.stompClient.subscribe('/nightly', (message) => {
            this._rootStore.dispatch(new UpdateNightlyAction(message));
        });
    });
}
```

When the connection is lost, the client logs the following:

```
POST https://<url>/api/socket/231/i0rsgjlx/xhr?t=1600673163228 404
Whoops! Lost connection to https://<url>/api/socket
```

I went through different scenarios of Websockets not working in Spring Boot 2 and nothing seemed to help. In 1.5 it works just fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

beacuse of springboot2.0^ is not allow cors param allowedOrigins = "*" , you can overwrite AllowedOriginPatterns equals "*"

boot1.5 ->

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration registration = registry.addEndpoint("/webSocket");
        registration.setAllowedOrigins("*");
        registration.withSockJS();
    }
```

boot2.0^->

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        StompWebSocketEndpointRegistration registration = registry.addEndpoint("/webSocket");
        // boot2.0^ AllowedOrigins = * is not allown
        registration.setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
        registration.withSockJS();
    }
```

I had a same error with yours, even search for a long time ,but there is no
answers,so i check the debug log find this problem,i fixed it with this method,it works!